# Isolating content with bashscript

Tags: regex, bash

I have this output of a terminal command:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root      908008 2014 07 02 zypper.log
```

I need to isolate only the  date portion so i can feed it in a custom message to the syslog.
I've tried  converting the output to an array - no success there and the sed regex matches only the whole line, not the specific part I need. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd
cd /var/log

destdir=/home/daka/Desktop/temp_date.txt

IFS=$'\n'
arr=( $(ls -l --time-style=+%Y' '%m' '%d |  grep 'zypper') )
unset IFS
if [ -f "$destdir" ]
then 
    echo "$arr" > "$destdir"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -l --time-style=+%Y' '%m' '%d |  grep 'zypper' | awk '{print $6,$7,$8}'
```

Comment: Any idea how to turn $6 $7 and $8  to variables or at least array elements? When I use 
varr=`ls -l --time-style=+%Y' '%m' '%d |  grep 'zypper' | awk '{print $6,$7,$8}'`
arr=($varr)
echo "$varr" > "$destdir"

it gives me only 2014 (the first element)

Comment: `arr=$(ls -l --time-style=+%Y' '%m' '%d |  grep 'zypper' | awk '{print $6,$7,$8}')` Then loop through them